# FileIOPermissionAccess Enumeration in vista

Tags: c#

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermissionaccess%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

According to the **Platforms**:

> Windows 98, Windows 2000 SP4, Windows Millennium Edition, Windows Server 2003, Windows XP Media Center Edition, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition, Windows XP SP2, Windows XP Starter Edition
>
> The .NET Framework does not support all versions of every platform. For a list of the supported versions, see System Requirements.

What about Vista?

Answer (score 3):

This is an older version of the page, created for FW2. Back then, Vista didn't exist.

Use the dropdown near the page title to see more recent revisions.